# Trying to change values in one value depending on values on another variable

Tags: r, dplyr, data-science, data-wrangling

I am trying to remove some NA's in one variable depending on the values gotten in a previous variable but I haven't managed to succeed...

Thanks in advance!

There are two variables: `info_geo` and `info_geo_actzd`. If the answer in the former one is "No", I want the answers in `info_geo_actzd` to change from "NA" to "No". The rest of the answers I want to leave them the same as now

I have tried various ways but I can't do it properly

```
db <- db %>%
    mutate(info_geo_actzd = case_when(
      info_geo == 'No' ~ "No",
      TRUE ~ .))
```

```
db <- db %>% 
  mutate(info_geo_actzd=ifelse('info_geo' == 'No' & 'info_geo_actzd' == 'NA', No))
```

I've also tried this but no result

```
db <- db  %>%
  mutate(info_geo_actzd = case_when(
    any(info_geo == 'No') ~ 'NA',
    TRUE ~ .))
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.` will return the dataset instead of the column.  If the `NA`s are unquoted, use `is.na` to create a logical vector and assign those to `"No"` or else (`TRUE`) return the original column `info_geo`

```
library(dplyr)
db <- db %>%
    mutate(info_geo_actzd = case_when(
      is.na(info_geo) ~ "No",
      TRUE ~ info_geo))
```

For more than one column, loop over the columns (either column index or column name - unquoted or quoted, or if there are any patterns in column names, wrap those in select-helpers -`contains/matches/starts_with/ends_with` etc)

```
db <- db %>%
    mutate(across(starts_with("info"), ~ case_when(is.na(.x) ~ "No",
         TRUE ~ .x), .names = "{.col}_actzd"))
```